# Navbar changes color when dropdown menu is added

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav bar that is black on my main page, but when I go to another page (with a dropdown) the nav bar changes to white. How can I keep it black on both pages?

link to main page: [index.html](http://www.germanwarletters.com/index.html#about)

link to letters: [slider.html.php](http://www.germanwarletters.com/slider.html.php?chapter=Introduction)

nav bar code of index.html

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">German War Letters</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Where to find the book</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

nav bar code of slider.html.php

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html#page-top">German War Letters</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                    <!--PAUL DROPDOWN CHAPTERS-->
                                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Chapters
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Introduction">Introduction</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter2TheHellerFamily">Chapter 2 The Heller Family</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter3HeinrichBredemeier">Chapter 3 Heinrich Bredemeier</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter4TheKetschauFamily">Chapter 4 The Ketschau Family</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter5RudolfZwingenberger">Chapter 5 Rudolf Zwingenberger</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter6TheJagelFamily">Chapter 6 The Jagel Family</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter7ErichKohler">Chapter 7 Erich Kohler</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter8Sgt.WalfriedGlase">Chapter 8 Sgt. Walfried Glase</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter9MomentsinTime">Chapter 9 Moments in Time</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter10TheHomefront">Chapter 10 The Homefront</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter11IntotheAbyss">Chapter 11 Into the Abyss</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="slider.html.php?chapter=Chapter12Sowhydidtheyfight">Chapter 12 So why did they fight?</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <!--END PAUL-->
                                    <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="index.html#contact">Where to find the book</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a live version of the site we can look at for reference? If not, hard to see whats going on without some CSS code to inspect. However, I'm assuming it's relating to your `navbar-toggle collapsed` class being overwritten or not being recognized. That would be my guess. If you inspect in the browser you'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @Jorden1337, I edited my post to provide links. Thanks for the suggestion!